# Dummy coefficients back to factor

Tags: r, glmnet, coefficients, dummy-variable

Say I have a trained glmnet model on a sparse matrix with multiple predictors containing a varying level of factors (and consequently varying number of dummy predictors).

```
df <- data.frame(y=runif(10), catVar=as.factor(sample(0:5,10,TRUE)))
A <- model.matrix(y ~ catVar,df) 
train <- cv.glmnet(A[,c('catVar3', 'catVar4')], df$y)
coef(train, s="lambda.min")
```

What would be the best (most efficient) approach to converting the dummy coefficients/values, or the overall formula, as if the dummy columns were not in a sparse format (just one column of varying factors)?

EDIT: I'm needing to convert the dummy coefficients and their slopes/values back to individual coefficients with varying slopes for each level.

Comment: Side comment: you probably want to remove the first column of your model matrix, since `glmnet` (and `cv.glmnet`) will add an intercept column automatically. It shouldn't affect the fit in terms of predicted values, but may lead to confusion when you're looking at the estimated coefficients.

Comment: Appreciate it - will make sure to remove prior to fitting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adapting a slick example from the [mailing list](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/R-how-to-convert-multiple-dummy-variables-to-1-factor-variable-td810654.html),

```
n <- length(levels(df$catVar))
factor(A%*%1:n, labels = levels(df$catVar))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `max.col` to get a vector of indices, then convert back to a factor, setting the levels to the column names.

Edit example:

```
X <- model.matrix(~group-1, sleep)                                               

factor(max.col(X), labels=colnames(X))
```

Comment: Could you share an example?

Comment: Thanks! What if the sparse model contained multiple 'original' factor variables, IE: Gender, Race, Language?

Answer (score 0):

Separate answer for sparse matrices. You can convert to triplet and read the index directly:

```
require(Matrix)                                                                  
X <- Diagonal(10)[sample(10,20,T), ]                                             
factor(as(X, "TsparseMatrix")@j, labels=LETTERS[1:10])
```

If your matrix is stored transposed, so you should be able to use `@i`.